# iOS5 @property changes

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, properties, automatic-ref-counting

In iOS 5, "retain" and "release" are not supported any more. Instead "strong" and "weak" are the new way.

**iOS 4 code:**

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)
@property(nonatomic, assign)
```

**iOS 5 code:**

```
???
???
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"In iOS 5, retain release are not supported any more." They are, just not when using ARC.

When using ARC, `-[<NSObject> retain]` is a no-op.

For properties, you can use `strong` if using ARC but that's not required (you can use `retain` too if you like). `strong` and `retain` are identical:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)
@property(nonatomic, assign)
```

Just make sure you are consistent (don't use both `strong` and `retain` in the same project).

Comment: BTW the Objective-C team did this to be backwards compatible with old code.

Comment: Any serious reasons for not using both strong/retain together? Is it just a readability concern?

Comment: @craig basically. I think it can be confusing to people new to ARC.

Comment: "When using ARC, -[<NSObject> retain] is a no-op." It's a compile-time error to send a `-retain` message, and it's not really a no-op since the compiler inserts these retains and release for you.  Also, `assign` has been replaced by `unsafe_unretained` and `weak`.  `weak` is recommended for applications targeting iOS 5.0+.  You can use `unsafe_unretained` for older applications, but as its name suggests it is not as safe as the automatically `nil`-ing weak properties.

Answer (score 5):

They are not exactly the same but basically `retain := strong` and `assign := weak`
I would suggest taking a look at the [ARC Release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html)

Comment: Actually, `assign` is closer to `unsafe_unretained` than `weak`.  Weak property assignments are a new concept.

Comment: Also note that weak will not work for primitive types such as int. You have to use assign.

Answer (score 4):

`nonatomic` property states that the object is not thread safe which means if a different thread tries to access this object than bad things can happen but this is much faster than atomic property.

`strong` is used with ARC and it basically helps you , by not having to worry about the retain count of an object. ARC automatically releases it for you when you are done with it.Using the keyword `strong` means that you own the object.

`weak` ownership means that you don't own it and it just keeps track of the object till the object it was assigned to stays , as soon as the second object is released it loses is value. For eg. `obj.a=objectB;` is used and a has weak property , than its value will only be valid till objectB remains in memory.

`copy` property is very well explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5002646/919545

`strong,weak,retain,copy,assign` are mutually exclusive so you can't use them on one single object... read the "Declared Properties " section of http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1

hoping this helps you out a bit...