# On retain and copy

Tags: objective-c, ios, copy, retain

I thought I had understand the difference between `retain` and `copy`. But when I met the code below I became confused again. These are the code:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableString *a;
    NSMutableString *b;
    NSMutableString *c;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *a;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *b;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *c;

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize a, b, c;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.a = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", @"aaa"];
    NSLog(@"a:%d", a.retainCount);

    self.b = a;
    NSLog(@"a:%d", a.retainCount);
    NSLog(@"b:%d", b.retainCount);

    self.c = b;
    NSLog(@"a:%d", a.retainCount);
    NSLog(@"b:%d", b.retainCount);
    NSLog(@"b:%d", c.retainCount);
}

@end
```

can anybody explain why the result is:

```
2011-12-31 16:54:50.244 RetainCopy[5783:207] a:1
2011-12-31 16:54:50.246 RetainCopy[5783:207] a:2
2011-12-31 16:54:50.246 RetainCopy[5783:207] b:2
2011-12-31 16:54:50.247 RetainCopy[5783:207] a:3
2011-12-31 16:54:50.247 RetainCopy[5783:207] b:3
2011-12-31 16:54:50.248 RetainCopy[5783:207] b:3
```

? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `-retainCount` is [useless to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784084/calling-retaincount-considered-harmful/5786253#5786253).

Second, one misunderstanding is in the implementation of the copy property implementation. You're not getting a copy here as you would expect. Instead, you are getting the result of `[arg copy]` rather than `[arg mutableCopy]`. Many immutable types 'copy' themselves like so (simplified):

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
  return [self retain];
}
```

so the result would ultimately be:

```
NSMutableString * a = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"aaa"];
NSString * b = [a copy]; // << returns an immutable copy!
NSString * c = [b copy]; // << immutable to immutable probably just retains itself!
```

Since they are immutable and pure, this is semantically sound. It also means that *you will need to implement copy accessors for mutable types yourself if the type makes a distinction between an immutable and a mutable copy*. Otherwise, your program could blow up when you attempt to mutate the ivar because you are holding an immutable instance. If you add this to the end of `-viewDidLoad`, you should see an exception: `[self.c appendString:@"uh-oh"];`

[More detail on implementing a mutable property here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995254/nsmutablestring-as-retain-copy/5004019#5004019).

Comment: To emphasize, **retainCount is utterly useless**.  Don't call it.  (Good answer).

Comment: One interesting point: `self.a = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", @"aaa"];` will set `a` to an immutable copy. The `NSMutableString` declaration on the property is ignored and would hopefully be flagged by the compiler (but isn't).