# Trying to use copied NSMutableString property causes an exception

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablestring, declared-property

I started a small Xcode project to investigate whether an `NSMutableString` property should be `copy` or `retain`. I declared my property with the `copy` attribute:

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableString *stringA;
```

Then initialized it as `self.stringA = [NSMutableString new];`

finally tried to set a string `[stringA setString:@"A"];`.

However the program gives,

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with setString:'"

Is it because the  resulting string is a `NSString`? Does this mean I should declare my `NSMutableString` properties using `retain` attribute and `NSString` properties using `copy` ?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want a mutable string as a property in the first place;  at least, not one that is exposed as API.

Comment: my answer, in too many words: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995254/nsmutablestring-as-retain-copy/5004019#5004019

Comment: It's pointless to use `copy` for NSStrings.

Comment: @HotLicks no it's not. remember semantics! what happens if a client passes a mutable string as a parameter to your class, you retain it, and then they mutate it behind your back? bad stuff. the simple solution is to make a copy -- if the parameter is mutable, then you have correctness, and a string you can easily pass without creating more copies. if it is immutable, then it could `return [self retain]` without making a deep copy.

Comment: What I understood so far is copy is important in NSString but not in NSMutableString. Since NSMutableString is a subclass of NSString , therfore you can assign a NSMutableString to NSString. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: @rustylepord well, it's not that it is not important -- the 'problem' is that `-[NSMutableString copy]` produces an *immutable* copy. for a mutable copy, you would use `mutableCopy`. `mutablecopy` is not a property specifier. so it's more like an edge case which is not supported by objc properties, and it's rarely useful or desirable. a mutable ivar, if really necessary, should typically be completely private. in most cases, immutable is the right choice. as well, you often don't want to retain a string you receive from an unknown source ; you will want to copy it because it may be mutable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right, the `copy` method of `NSMutableString` returns an *immutable* `NSString`. This is a convention in Cocoa, it also applies to `NSMutableArray`, `NSMutableDictionary`, etc.

So if you want your property to remain mutable, you should declare it as `retain`. If you need copy semantics, but still want the result to be mutable, you'd have to implement your own setter for the property (and use `mutableCopy` to do the copying).

The reason you commonly see `copy` for string properties is that it's often desirable to have a guarantee that a string is immutable, regardless of what kind of string is assigned to the property. Otherwise you might end up accidentally modifying the same string elsewhere, which can be difficult to debug. Immutable objects also have the benefit of being thread-safe.

Comment: SO basically I should use copy for NString, NSArray , NSDictionary types since there mutable variants and for the mutable types like NSMutableString , NSMutableArray I should use retain. Is this correct?

Answer (score -1):

The first question I would ask is how stringA was initialized. If you set it from a plain String then it may be why you are getting that. Copy and Retain actually performs differently and you should know why you would use one or the other.

Copy is actually making a copy of the memory so that any changes you do to that property do not affect the original it was set from where retain only increments the retain count of the memory so you ensure that it will not be released until you are done referencing it.

Comment: I intialized it as self.stringA = [NSMutableString new];

Comment: initialize it as self.stringA = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; and see if it change anything

Comment: `new` is just shorthand for `alloc init`, they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Just making it retain will probably fix it as omz said.