# What's the typical use-case of the copy properties attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

What's the typical use-case of the `copy` properties' attribute?

When should I copy some value instead of just incrementing reference count as it can be achieved via the `strong` property?

Comment: Put a two `NSMutableString` property to an object, one `copy`, one `strong`. Do `NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello "];` and set it to both the property of your object. Logs the two properties. Then do `[string appendString:@"World"];`, log again the two properties. You'll see. Do the same and look at the objects addresses.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: if the property is a pointer to a class which adopts the `NSCopying` protocol, the property should have the `copy` attribute unless you have a really good reason why it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have answered this before, so I'll just point you to a couple of them.

First, the Apple docs:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html, search for "Copy Properties Maintain Their Own Copies"

Here is a pretty good explanation of the various property attributes:  [Objective-C declared @property attributes (nonatomic, copy, strong, weak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859719/objective-c-declared-property-attributes-nonatomic-copy-strong-weak)

This answer does a good job of explaining a pretty typical use case and why you'd use copy:  [NSMutableString as retain/copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995254/nsmutablestring-as-retain-copy/5002646#5002646)

Neither, however, mentions block properties, and you *never* want to use anything *other* than `copy` for blocks (assuming, of course, that you're using ARC, and ARC even handles this for you automatically):

> Note: You should specify copy as the property attribute, because a
>   block needs to be copied to keep track of its captured state outside
>   of the original scope. This isn’t something you need to worry about
>   when using Automatic Reference Counting, as it will happen
>   automatically, but it’s best practice for the property attribute to
>   show the resultant behavior. For more information, see Blocks
>   Programming Topics.

From here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: Actually, you doesn't need explicitly copy blocks under ARC. This mentioned even in provided quote from documentation: "This isn’t something you need to worry about when using Automatic Reference Counting, as it will happen automatically"

Comment: Fair point.  I personally like to be explicit about certain things (including), but it's by no means required.  I suppose my comment *should* have read "You never want to use anything *other* than `copy` for blocks, but you don't need to explicitly specify it".  Thanks for the clarification, I've edited my comment accordingly.