# Do I use retain or copy in my singleton?

Tags: iphone, ios

I read somewhere that with NSString in an object, one has to use copy instead of retain. Can someone explain if this is correct and why?

For example I have the following declaration for my singleton:

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>
@class FaxRecipient;

@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    NSString *subject;
    NSString *reference;
    NSString *coverSheet;
    FaxRecipient *faxRecipient;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *test1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *test2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *test3;
@property (nonatomic,retain) FaxRecipient *faxRecipient;



+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

Comment: The code that you mentioned is correct. You have to use retain.

Comment: It's my understanding to use retain as well. I'd be interested to here of alternative theories and the reasons for them. One reason that does spring to mind is that copying means that if you get passed a NSMutableString instead of a NSString then your class is not effected if the mutable string is changed by another class. NSString would be different because it's fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387959/nsstring-property-copy-or-retain

Comment: @Derek Clarkson, that's exactly the reason that you should use 'copy' in this case. If someone sets the test1 property to a NSString*, the copy is implemented as a retain anyway, so no difference. If they pass in a NSMutableString*, though, an immutable copy is made and the property points to that, so no surprises.

Comment: @Caleb - True, I wasn't referring to the sample code. Just giving my general understanding :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think "has to" in the sense of *must* is a little strong. You *can* use either `copy` or `retain`, but you *should* generally use `copy` for your `NSString*` properties because:

1. You usually don't want a string property to change under your nose;
2. `NSMutableString` is a subclass of `NSString`, so it's entirely possible that someone might set your `NSString*` property to point to a mutable string, thus creating the potential for the string to be changed while you're using it;
3. For immutable classes like `NSString`, copy operations end up just retaining the original object anyway.

Considering those three points, it's hard to think of a good reason to use `retain` instead of `copy` for your `NSString` properties.

Comment: one could use `assign` as well! ;)

Answer (score 4):

prefer `copy`. it does not matter whether your class is or is not a singleton.

i wrote a fairly lengthy explanation for this, which details mutable and immutable types here:
[NSMutableString as retain/copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995254/nsmutablestring-as-retain-copy/5004019#5004019)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use copy instead of retain. I use copy for NSString. There is good discussion on this topic. Here is a stackoverflow post [NSString Copy or Retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587414/nsstring-property-using-copy-instead-of-retain)

Answer (score 0):

You could use either,**In both cases** you will be **owner** of the objects and need to be released in **dealloc**.

Difference between `copy` and `retain` .

**retain :**--> It just increase the retain count on the exist object.

**copy   :**--> it crate the new object for your property

In both cases: you will have the ownership of objects.

Read Apple [memory management concept](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

**@ Claus Broch: From Apple Documentation**

> You take ownership of an object if you
>   create it using a method whose name
>   begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or
>   “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc,
>   newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you
>   send it a retain message.

Comment: @Jhaliya Just because you retain an object doesn't mean you become the owner. As @Caleb points out there is no way you are protected against somebody sendin you a NSMutableString and changing that later on.

Comment: @Claus Broch  : So tell ... why do we use retain ?

Comment: @Jhaliya To get our own reference to an object thus ensuring it doesn't get deallocated when everybody else looses interest in it

Comment: @Claus Broch  : Good definition , my other question , Do you own it release ?

Comment: @Jhaliya I would bend that definition by Apple to say "responsibility" or "shared ownership" instead of "ownership". You do not get an exclusive ownership over an object by retaining it. The original question from @milofaris specifically asked about NSString and as @Caleb pointed out you do not have fully exclusive ownership over that object by using retain.

Comment: @Claus Broch  : no offense but would advice you to read apple documentation and correct yourself whether  they say "responsibility" , "shared ownership" OR "ownership" which i used in my answer.

Comment: @Jhaliya: No offense either. No point in starting a war on words. In regards to that part of the Apple docs you're perfectly right in your use of the terms. But there is more to it than that - which was what I was trying to explain.

Comment: @Claus Broch : you are absolutely with your words,thanks for healthy conversion..

Answer (score -2):

You should use the retain value in this instance. The reason for this is that 
1. you don't want the object to be deallocated
2. you are most likely going to want to change the value of the NSString at some point

Using the copy attribute is basically saying that the value of your NSString should not change without warning. i.e. it will stop the value of the NSString being set and retrieved at the same time.

For this implementation, you should use retain, or at least thats my understanding. For more look here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/06/assign-retain-copy-pitfalls-in-obj-c.html